# How do we remove Static NAT from 2801 Router?

Tags: cisco, nat

We have Cisco 2801 router , which uses static NAT translation.The problem is that we are not able to remove the NAT entry from the 2801 router.

We tested with the following commands:

```
(config)#clear ip nat translation*
```

The router will take the command but nothing happens.

Tried adding another NAT to the existing line, then the result was:

```
(config)#ip nat outside source static tcp 192.168.3.11 80 201.x.x.x 80 extendable

% similar static entry (192.168.3.11-> 201.x.x.x ) already exists
```

So, how can we permanently delete this NAT?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your router configuration.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to look at your existing configuration (`sh run` from an enabled prompt) and find the existing NAT configuration (`ip nat inside...` or `ip nat outside...` with the dots being the remainder of the command).
2. Enter configuration mode ("conf t")
3. Type "no" before the line to be removed.  So - for example - if it presently has something like "ip nat inside source ..." you would type "**no** ip nat inside source..."
4. At this point you should be able to enter the new translation command.

Don't forget to save your configuration when you're done.